# Do mussels contain creatine?

Tags: diet, vegetarian

I am a vegan, but I'm fine with eating bivalves like mussels.
Vegans tend to have lower creatine levels, but I don't really want to supplement. So my question: do mussels contain creatine?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about hey dawg I heard you like creatine so I put some in your mussels for your muscles.

Comment: why are you eating mussels if you're a vegan?

Comment: Well I can't say I'm vegan in the strictest sense, what really matters to me is whether the animal can suffer or not. Current science says that mussels aren't sentient so I don't see a problem with consuming them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the nutritional highlight section of the [Wikipedia article for mussels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mussel), it does not seem to contain any measurable amount of creatine.

Answer (score 2):

I have not seen any documentation about mussles having creatine. 
But what I know is that Vegetarians should pay attention to an adequate supply of amino acids arginine, glycine and methionine, which are used in the production of creatine. Arginine is found in peanuts, walnuts, coconuts, soybeans, chickpeas and oats; Glycine in raw seaweed or spirulina, raw watercress, spinach, soy protein isolate, and sesame seeds. Brazil nuts, oats and sunflower seeds are good sources of methionine. But still with adequate diet considering the stuff above your creatine level will probably be lower to 'carnivoirs' ...